# Localhost with meteor.js displays main.html instead of other files

Tags: meteor, localhost

I have a problem with meteor.js installed on a localhost.
Basically I have an image stored both in public/apple.png and at the same folder as main.html, but it doesn't compare in the page.
Another interesting thing is also when I type localhost:3000/apple.png it doesn't show me the image, but rather it outputs the main.html page. Same thing for localhost:3000/something: it only shows me main.html rather than an error.

main.html

```
 <head>
      <title>simple</title>
 </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

      {{> hello}}
    </body>

    <template name="hello">
     <img src="apple.png" alt="Apple Computer">
    </template>
```

Any tips?

Comment: Are you using a router i.e. iron-router by any chance?

Comment: Try to remove all apple.png files except one located in public folder